# Create a ROC curve in python, but find the confusion matrix may not generate correctly

Tags: python

I created the model to plot the curve. I could see the curve, but do not feel it correct.

After some debug, I found the confusion matrix did not equal to the one I got without split to train & test data. I used the test size as 0.25, the default value to split dataset.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code. Can anyone help to check? Thanks

```
# Import the libraries we will be using
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Load the data
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
# Let's take a look at the data
data.head()


# Split our data
X = data.drop(['Actual'], axis=1)
Y = data['Actual']
X_data_train, X_data_test, Y_data_train, Y_data_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)


# Make and fit a model on the training data
model_data = LogisticRegression(C=1000000, solver='liblinear')
model_data.fit(X_data_train, Y_data_train)

# Get probabilities of being a (We saw this last class !!)
probabilities = model_data.predict_proba(X_data_test)[:, 1]


prediction = probabilities > 0.5

# Build and print a confusion matrix
confusion_matrix_large = pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(Y_data_test, prediction, labels=[1, 0]).T,
                                columns=['p', 'n'], index=['Y', 'N'])
print (confusion_matrix_large)



# Let's move the threshold down
prediction = probabilities > 0.05

# Build and print a confusion matrix
confusion_matrix_small = pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix(Y_data_test, prediction, labels=[1, 0]).T,
                                columns=['p', 'n'], index=['Y', 'N'])
print (confusion_matrix_small)


# Use the metrics.roc_curve function to get the true positive rate (tpr) and false positive rate (fpr)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(Y_data_test, probabilities)
    
    # Get the area under the curve (AUC)
    auc = np.mean(cross_val_score(model_data, X, Y, scoring="roc_auc", cv=5))

    # Plot the ROC curve
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label="AUC (C=" + str(data) + ") = " + str(round(auc, 2)))
    
plt.xlabel("False positive rate (fpr)")
plt.ylabel("True positive rate (tpr)")
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], 'k--', label="Random")
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: Please title your question correctly; you say the issue is wrong confusion matrix, not "ROC curve". But your code is generating `confusion_matrix_small = pd.DataFrame(metrics.confusion_matrix...` but then using `fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(...)` and plotting the ROC curve `plt.plot(fpr, tpr, ...)`. Did you write this code yourself or just copy it? If so, what have you tried to debug it? You have to do this. It's [not allowed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to just post a wall of code and ask "Why isn't this doing what it's supposed to?"

Comment: Also, can you format the section with 'Correct confusion matrix' and 'Split matrix', it's illegible?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Python. I learned the usage from scikit-learn. I may use the wrong part. That's something I could you can point it out. Thanks

Comment: Ok but you're still plotting two different things, and you need to go digging into that, and understand what the code is doing and why. This questions needs more focus, clarity, detail. Did this code come from some tutorial? Check with them.

Comment: I fixed the issue to create a function to do the math and plot.